# How to Make Time Buffering for keyPressed() Function in P5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I made a simple Snake game in the P5.js environment,
and I have one thing that I want to fix.

So, I have this code for `keyPressed()` function

```
function keyPressed(){
    if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        if(snake.yspeed == 1 || snake.yspeed == -1) {
            snake.yspeed = 0;
            snake.xspeed = -1;
        }
    }else if(keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
        if(snake.yspeed == 1 || snake.yspeed == -1) {
            snake.yspeed = 0;
            snake.xspeed = 1;
        }
    }else if(keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
        if(snake.xspeed == 1 || snake.xspeed == -1) {
            snake.xspeed = 0;
            snake.yspeed = -1;
        }
    }else if(keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
        if(snake.xspeed == 1 || snake.xspeed == -1) {
            snake.xspeed = 0;
            snake.yspeed = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

`yspeed` is the vertical movement, and `xspeed` is the horizontal movement.

So, if the snake is moving to the right, even if I pressed the `LEFT_ARROW` , the snake won't turn to the left. But, if I pressed `UP_ARROW` or `DOWN_ARROW` and quickly press the `LEFT_ARROW`, the snake will immediately turn left and hit itself.

So, I want to add a buffering time for the `keyPressed()` function after one of the arrow keys being pressed.

How can I do this in P5.js?

Comment: Could you share a link to your source code?

Comment: Try the [`keyReleased`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyReleased) method instead.

Comment: @JoshHabdas That wouldn't exactly solve the problem since you can tap the two keys instead of holding them down, although it might make it a bit better.

Comment: Cool. I tried to grok the API docs but didn't see anything obvious to solve for your use case in `p5.js` (thanks for making me aware of it). Nevertheless in common use it's almost always better to use `keyup` when designing UIs because [reasons].

Comment: here is my source code: rendyeza.github.io/Snake/index,html @ARatherLongName

Answer (score 1):

I also made a [snake game](https://justaratherridiculouslylongusername.github.io/Snake/) and encountered this exact problem.
I wrote it in vanilla javascript and had set the fps to 12, which give the player enough time to change direction twice between two cycles.

---

## Solution

My solution was to have a buffer variable that stores the last pressed direction. in your case, it could look like so

```
let dir = '';
function keyPressed(){
    if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) dir = 'LEFT';

    if(keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) dir = 'RIGHT';

    if(keyCode === UP_ARROW) dir = 'UP';

    if(keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) dir = 'DOWN';

}
```

And actually change its direction only before I called the snake's `update()` method in `draw()`:

```
function draw() {
    ...
    snake.direction(dir);
    snake.update();
    snake.draw();
    ...
}
```

You only need to check whether or not the move is valid within the `direction()` method.

```
this.direction = function(d) {
    switch(d) {
        case 'LEFT':
            if (this.xv != 1) {this.xv = -1; this.yv = 0;}
            break;

        case 'RIGHT':
            if (this.xv != -1) {this.xv = 1; this.yv = 0;}
            break;

        case 'UP':
            if (this.yv != 1) {this.xv = 0; this.yv = -1;}
            break;

        case 'DOWN':
            if (this.yv != -1) {this.xv = 0; this.yv = 1;}
            break;

        default:
            this.xv = this.yv = 0;

    }

}
```

(I copied this from my code, but you get the idea)

---

## How it works

Lets take your example.

In your game, what is happening is that it first changes the velocity of the snake to point `UP`, then to the `LEFT`, all before the next `snake.update()` is called.

Now all it does is change the `dir` variable to `UP`, then `LEFT` before the next `snake.update()` is called. So the next `snake.direction()` gets a `dir` argument containing `LEFT`, which is ignored (because the snake is pointing `RIGHT`) and the snake doesn't go backward on itself.

---

I hope this made some sense, you can check my code [here](https://github.com/JustARatherRidiculouslyLongUsername/Snake) if it helps.

Comment: cool. I get the idea, because in my code I don't call the keypressed function into draw function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a time limit on the key presses, by doing something like checking that `draw()` was called at least once between key presses. Something like this:

```
var canPress = true;

function keyPressed(){
  if(canPress){
    // respond to key press
  }
  canPress = false;
}

function draw(){
  // draw the frame

  canPress = true;
}
```

But my guess is that this will make your game feel clunky and unresponsive.

Instead of restricting user input based on time, there are two general solutions for this:

**Option 1:** Move the snake immediately when the user presses the corresponding key. You'd do this by calling something like an `update()` function, both at the beginning of each frame, and when you press a key.

**Option 2:** Prevent the snake from moving in a direction that would kill itself immediately. You'd do this by checking whether the square you're about to go in is occupied, and ignoring the key press if so.

Which approach you take depends on how you want your game to work. You could even take a hybrid approach and do both.

Comment: These are good ideas, but they add bugs of their own:

**Option 1:** the player can spam a single key or two adjacent keys to move quicker than intended


**Option 2:** The player can't die (by pressing right arrow) in [this situation](https://ibin.co/4CJjktjvri9i.png) .

Comment: @ARatherLongName I don't think either one is necessarily a bug. Like I said, the approach you take depends on how you want your game to work.

Comment: Right, but then nothing is necessarily a bug. It's just that most people would usually call it one, since it isn't how the game is normally works.

Comment: @ARatherLongName I think you'd be surprised. Option 1 is exactly how many implementations of snake work. Limiting user input with a timeout is going to feel much more buggy than being more responsive.

Comment: @ARatherLongName Uh, what? Snake is an extremely popular game with a bunch of different implementations. I'm not saying that your approach is **wrong**. I'm saying there are **other valid approaches**. I personally would not go with a delay, but like I've said a couple times now: all of this depends on how you want your game to work. But if you're curious, [Google's Snake game](https://www.google.com/search?q=snake) takes the approach of updating whenever the user presses a key.